# Strings and performance

Tags: java, string, performance

I have a for loop like this :

```
    String myString = "123456789";
    String prefix = null;
    for (int i=6;i>=0;--i)
    {
       prefix = myString.substring(0,i);
       process(prefix);
    }
```

The problem is that if this block of code is executed N times, N*7 strings will be created (7 strings will be created for each execution - because the substring method creates a new String and this method is called 7 times for each execution).
I'm thinking about how to improve performance in this case. I wanted to know if there is a way to use only one String per execution with this being modified each time. That's the purpose of the StringBuilder, but i think the StringBuilder doesn't help in this case :

```
    String myString = "123456789";
    StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder(myString);
    for (int i=6;i>=0;--i)
    {
       prefix.delete(i,prefix.length());
       process(prefix.toString());
    }
```

In this case, prefix always reference the same StringBuilder object, but the same problem appears at another place because prefix.toString() returns always a new String object.

Any idea?

(I know that the topic has been treated many times. But i've done some search and i didn't find solution, maybe that's the minimal use of memory?)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can't you change the process method to work with a StringBuilder? Or better, a CharSequence so it accepts both?

Comment: can you have process take the `StringBuilder` (or a `CharSequence` to take the most specific common super type)

Comment: Define "improve performance". Is the code executing too slow? Is it using too much memory? If so, how much do you need it to use/how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. If I change the process method to get a StringBuilder instead of a String, i'll use the same String inside the code, and if i pass this StringBuilder to the process method, someone at the ends needs the String and I will need to call the toString() method which creates a new String.                          @JRL I used VisualVM and I see that most of the memory is used by Strings, maybe that's a normal situation, but I wanted to know what are the ways to reduce this use of Strings (or memory).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is true that `myString.substring(0, i)` creates a new `String` object, please note that this does not copy the underlying character data.

Before doing anything to this code, I would use a profiler to verify that this is indeed a bottleneck (either in terms of CPU usage, or in terms of strain placed on the garbage collector).

Comment: Thanks! like you said, it uses always the same char[] (value field) so the problem may exists only for millions of call to substring. That's not my case.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the goal of this?

You're right, there are 7 instance of string created during your loop, but as strings are inmutable all of them don't store a copy of the source string but are only a reference to the old string (which is save, because it can't change), therefor consuming not really that much memory.

Comment: I'm guessing the real-world problem is about larger values for `i`, or millions of processing iterations

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by use of memory?

If you use your second method, a new string will be created yes, but Java's garbage collector will remove the string from memory once the method has been popped off the call stack (ie. the method has finished). So you'll only have 2 strings at any one given time - The original string and the prefix string.

Comment: I know that these Strings are released after the return but I've read that if I use less objects (in this case less Strings), the GC will be called less often, and it increases the execution time, because it has less objects to release from memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need that optimisation, then the only option I can see is to pass the index to the process method and operate on the original string within that method:

```
for (int i=6;i>=0;--i)
{
   process(prefix, i);
}
```

Depending on what the process method does, this might indeed be slightly faster for large values of `i`

Answer (score 0):

"I wanted to know if there is a way to use only one String per execution with this being modified each time." - nope, that won't work as the String class is immutable. If you have code that needs to modify a lot of stings of characters, I recommend using StringBuilder exclusively (i.e. modify your "process" method to accept a StringBuilder argument).